# Remover Colunas de um arquivo .csv com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arquivo, csv

Abaixo segue meu código para a leitura de um arquivo .csv utilizando Nodejs, gostaria de saber como posso remover as colunas "EMPRESA" e "%" do arquivo 'file.csv', desde já muito obrigado ao que contribuírem.

```js
var fs = require('fs')
var csv = require('fast-csv')
var list = []

fs.createReadStream('file.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', data => {

    list = data;

    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      console.log(list[i])
    }
  })
  .on('end', function (data) {
    console.log('\nleitura finalizada!')
  })
```

Link do File.csv que é usado na referência do código: [Download do file.csv](https://mega.nz/#!5kAGGSbY!2T--mKhxKxnebc3GaL6fy_xbZ1nu6B5dqLDj_MU8mX0)

Utilizado a biblioteca fast-csv link da documentação: [Documentação do fast-csv](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv/blob/HEAD/docs/parsing.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realizei as seguintes alterações no trecho ".on({ alterado-aqui })", sendo necessário a criação da variável output. isto solucionou meu problema em relação a omissão das colunas "EMPRESA" e "%".

```js
//Declarações de variaveis globais:
let output = ''

  //Trecho alterado:
  .on('data', data => {

    if (list[i] == null) {
      list[i] = data.CREDENCIADO + ';' + data.USUARIO.substring(2) + ';' + data['AUTORIZACAO'] + ';' + data['DATA AUT'] + ';' + data['DATA VEN'] + ';' + data.PARCELA + ';' + data['TOTAL PARCELAS'] + ';' + 'R$ ' + data.VALOR.replace('.', ',').toLocaleString('pt-br', {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: 'BRL'
      }) + '\n'

      if (output == '') {
        output = list[i]
        console.log(list[i])
        i++
      } else {
        output += list[i]
        console.log(list[i])
        i++
      }
    }
  })
```

Código de Exemplo no Github: [FORMATTER-CSV-TO-XLSX-NODE-JAVASCRIPT](https://github.com/DioneCarlos/FORMATTER-CSV-TO-XLSX-NODE-JAVASCRIPT)